# Sharepoint 2013 not going to http://sharepoint/SitePages/Home.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, redirect

Currently in my Sharepoint Site, when I want to go to the main page sharepoint/SitePages/Home.aspx, it actually ends up going to sharepoint/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx.

This really wouldn't be that big of an issue except my embed Javascript doesn't show up in the page its being redirected to. Any help to solve this would be amazing

Comment: possible duplicate of [External access gives a blank home page](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/external-access-gives-a-blank-home-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please refer to this answer that i answered about the minimal download stratergy ;)

[External access gives a blank home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/external-access-gives-a-blank-home-page)

to stop it do the following:

go to:

Site settings > under Site Actions section > manage site feature

now disable the feature MDSFeature and it will keep on that link instead of redirecting ;)