# Error "fullPageLoadRequired"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, sub-site

I got this error when i try create subsite on my sharepoint server 2013.

> 0|fullPageLoadRequired|__Page||

I can't find information about this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you added any javascript files? looks like its loading some javascript before the sp.js file?

Comment: I made subsite with master (Site Actions -> Site Content -> Add subsite). I didn't add custom javascript files.

Comment: Today i got another error:  50|pageStartRedirect||http://server-dev/test-list/_layouts/15/start.aspx|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today i got another error:
>   50|pageStartRedirect||server-dev/test-list/_layouts/15/start.aspx| – 
>   Dmitriy N. Laykom

try to access without going to the mds page:

more about it can be found here in my answer:

[External access gives a blank home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/external-access-gives-a-blank-home-page)

the above might also solve your original issue as its asking for a full page load instead of cashed load by Minimal Download Strategy.

**EDIT**

turn off mds using powershell:

```
 # Get All Web Applications
$WebApps=Get-SPWebApplication
foreach($webApp in $WebApps)
{
    foreach ($SPsite in $webApp.Sites)
    {
       # get the collection of webs
       foreach($SPweb in $SPsite.AllWebs)
        {
            write-host $SPweb.title ":" $spweb.URL;

              Disable-SPFeature –identity "MDSFeature" -URL $spweb.URL -confirm:$false
        }
    }
  }
```

http://www.sharepointastic.com/Pages/SharePoint2013MDS.aspx

Comment: Unfortenatly it doesn't work for me. I terned off Minimal Download Strategy, but problem didn't solved.

Comment: just wondering this only occures for the subsite? if so have you tried making a new subsite with a different masterpage?, somthing is going wrong around the masterpage region with javascript for some reason!

Comment: i tried different master pages and i used sharepoint designer. But problem didn't solved.

Comment: just to make sure do you have full control? you need it to make a subsite, also just want clarification that your parent site works fine, the what masterpage are you using and what layouts page. make sure they are default and havent been changed/edited!! just seems a bit strange as its deffo a JS issue where its not loading properly! have you tried debugging in ie or firefox or using fiddler? that way you know where in JS its going wrong!

Comment: Yes i have full control on this site.

Comment: Can I turn off the MDS using Powershell?

Comment: just ammended my answer!